# Can anyine explain what exactly is a map?

Tags: functions

What is meant by,

A map is a triple $f = (A,B,Γ) $

I came across this when reading a book in set theory. Don’t understand what is exactly meant by this notation. Later in the text, the author says that the map $f$ is also called a function and that set $A$ is domain, set $B$ is codomain and set $Γ$ is the graph if $f$. What us exactly meant by the notation used in the statement above ? Can this notation be used to describe other functions ?

Comment: Do you know what is a function in general?

Comment: I don't know why this post is being down-voted. Many beginning math students are exposed to functions in a more intuitive way and a set-theoretic definition can be confusing. That said, @Srinidhi you could proof read your post to at least show us you are serious. I don't expect you to be a master of the English language but there is no excuse for "anyine" and "I cane across".

Comment: Thank you @JohnDouma for your comment. Sorry for my spelling error, it was a typing mistake. I know what a function is, but i wanted to learn it more deeply and that’s when i came across this set-theoretic notation. I have usually seen this notation being used to describe multivariabke functions, that’s why i got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an alternate way to define functions instead of the other more common approach of relations.

Yes, it can be used to define any function. Conventionally, a function is defined by a relation between the domain and codomain. For example, we can define a function $f:\,\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=2x$. What did you need to define for the function to be defined fully? The domain, what values you can put in $x$, the codomain, where the values must lie, (it may not be apparent but this is important for defining  surjectivity), and the relation on how you can find the value of the function at some point.

The alternative notation $f\,(A, B,\Gamma)$ is the same. Here, $A$ is domain, $B$ is codomain and $\Gamma$ is the graph. It just replaces the relation with a graph $\Gamma$. The two are equivalent, because you can graph a relation as such.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I know what a function is, but i haven’t come across this notation before so I got confused. I have usually seen this notation being used for multivariable functions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Srinidhikabra: I was just going through my old answers, and found that you haven't accepted this. So, I would recommend to accept this answer so as the website and other people know that your query is resolved.